# Is there a way to create a Makefile without running ./configure?

Tags: makefile, configure

I'd like to skip the tests and create a (default) Makefile.

Comment: Why?  What is the purpose?  What do you mean my "default"?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can write a makefile by hand. A quick googling shows LOTS of tutorials. [This one](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) looks promising.

For the cliffs notes version, the example boils down this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Nitpick: The prevalent convention is to use CC and CFLAGS for the C compiler (gcc) and CXX and CXXFLAGS for the C++ compiler (g++).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to second guess what the author laboured over?  People don't generate configure scripts for fun - they generate configure scripts because determining the correct way to compile the program on *your* system is hard and running `./configure` is easier than all the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Perl, there's always good ol'

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    'NAME' => 'Foo::Bar',
    'DISTNAME' => 'Foo-Bar',
    'EXE_FILES' => ["foobar.sh"],
    'VERSION_FROM' => 'lib/Foo/Bar.pm',
    );
```

However, your question is a bit short, if you are merely building an **existing** project you may find it impossible to skip configure.